# Does transmutation of nuclear waste need more energy than it originally produced?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Nuclear transmutation has been proposed as a method to reduce nuclear waste from nuclear power plants:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation

I recall reading somewhere that this is economically not very attractive, because it basically needs more energy to transmute the nuclear waste than the burning of the nuclear material produced in the first place. However I couldn't find any good source for this claim, so maybe this is wrong. It might also depend on the method of transmutation (with fast breeders or accelerator driven systems). Does anyone know how much energy transmutation needs in comparison to the energy produced by the nuclear material? How much would transmutation on industrial scale lower the total efficiency of energy production in nuclear power plants?

Comment: I have to say this seems like an engineering problem to me. If you're prepared to wait an infinite time all elements (radioactive or not) will transform to harmless iron. The problem is that speeding this up costs energy and it's finding some efficient way to "catalyse" the transformation that is the problem. The physics is pretty trivial, it's the engineering involved that is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://fissilematerials.org/blog/2010/02/history_and_status_of_fas.html) describes some of the reasons we don't use nuclear waste as fuel.

The biggest problem is that we have plenty of uranium (and other energy sources) and burying the waste is not very expensive so there is not a large economical incentive to burn the rest of the fuel. This in turn leads to less interest in developing a reactor that can do what you suggest. So even though more energy may come out than you put in, it may not be worth the monetary investment to research and develop these reactors.